# Build Error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token .polyfills - Chrome Headless

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins, tsconfig, polyfills

I am getting an error while building my Angular App on Jenkins. Am upgrading from Angular8 to Angular15 with no errors in my local. I believe my issue could be somewhere on polyfills.ts. tsconfig.app.json, package.json, or angular.json, karma.conf.js.

There are no issues in my local on nodejs18 and Angular15

```
Chrome Headless 69.0.3497.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:1381:32
```

Removing test.ts and updating polyfills on angular.json to include zone.js and zone.js/testing. On tsconfig.app.json, I removed polyfills.ts from "files"

Comment: can you confirm if it's resolved or not? I can't use FirefoxHeadless, so if anyone had resolved the issue with ChromeHeadless , please help here

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. I could resolve it by using `FirefoxHeadless` instead of `ChromeHeadless`.

Install `karma-firefox-launcher`: Add the `karma-firefox-launcher` package to your project's `devDependencies`. You can do this by running the following command in your project's directory:

```bash
npm install karma-firefox-launcher --save-dev
```

Adjust `karma.conf.js`: Open the `karma.conf.js` file in your project. Inside this file, you should have a configuration object for Karma. Find the browsers property and add `FirefoxHeadless` to the array of browsers:

```json
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // ... other configurations ...
    browsers: ['FirefoxHeadless'],
    // ... other configurations ...
  });
};
```

Add `karma-firefox-launcher` to the plugin section: In the same `karma.conf.js` file, find the plugins property and make sure `karma-firefox-launcher` is included in the array:

```json
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // ... other configurations ...
    plugins: [
      // ... other plugins ...
      require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
    ],
    // ... other configurations ...
  });
};
```